# Returning list of lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having a tough time figuring out why my function `buildList-aux` does not return the correct contents of the list `Z`.

When I run debug mode, and pause on the if statement above return `Z`, I can see that the value in `racket` is correct and as expected, however the actual contents that gets returned and printed have some sort of error (overflow? or something) and prints `(shared ((-1- (list 'abc))) (list -1- -1-))`.

I'm running DrRacket 6.11, Advanced Student language.

```
(define buildList-aux
  (lambda (E Z count)
    (if (<= count 0)
        Z
        (if (not (list? E))
            (buildList-aux E (append (list E) Z) (- count 1))
            (buildList-aux E (cons E Z) (- count 1))))))

(define buildList
  (lambda (N E)
    (buildList-aux E '() N)))

(buildList 5 '())
(buildList 3 'A)
(buildList 2 '(abc))
(buildList 3 '(A))
```

Expected Output:

```
(list '() '() '() '() '())
(list 'A 'A 'A)
(list (list 'abc) (list 'abc))
(list (list 'A) (list 'A) (list 'A))
```

Actual Output:

```
(list '() '() '() '() '())
(list 'A 'A 'A)
(shared ((-1- (list 'abc))) (list -1- -1-))
(shared ((-1- (list 'A))) (list -1- -1- -1-))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, it's just the way a list gets displayed in "Advanced Student". To see the correct output, do as @JohnClements suggests and go to "Language Details", and uncheck "Show Sharing in Values" box. Alternatively, switch to "Detect language from source" and specify `#lang racket` at the top of the file. Either way, the output will be as expected:

```
'(() () () () ())
'(A A A)
'((abc) (abc))
'((A) (A) (A))
```

But let's take a look at that weird output:

```
(shared ((-1- (list 'abc))) (list -1- -1-))
```

The above is stating that the result is:

```
(list -1- -1-)
```

Think of the `-1-` as a "variable" representing shared data, with a value of `(list 'abc)`. If we substitute the "variable" with its value we get the more familiar:

```
(list (list 'abc) (list 'abc))
```

Comment: I'm supposed to use "Advanced Student", is there a way to get the desired output using it, or must I switch to regular racket language?

Comment: The output _is_ already correct, it's just the way that's displayed that's weird - but that's not your fault. To avoid this inconvenience, better switch to regular racket.

Comment: No need to switch language levels... go to Language>Choose Language..., click on "Language Details", and uncheck "Show Sharing in Values" box. Changing language levels is likely to have other effects that you may not expect or want.